Numpy doesn't functioning in visual studio code
I installed numpy library version 1.25.x because my python version is 3.11.3(via anaconda)  but  in visual studio code program the command like np.array() does not excute. Is it compatible issue or something else?
I've upgraded my pip and then install another version of numpy (version 2.0.0) but the problem wasn't go away, then I searched for compatible version and find out version 1.25.x is compatible with python 3, but the issue still there. so can someone please tell me what should I do?

"tell me what should I do?": give us more information. What error do you get?

Hello, did you check which environment you are using in VSCode ?

You should further elaborate the specifics of the issue you are facing, so that the people can help. i.e. what kind of error do you get? have you checked whether the issue is in VS Code, and not due to mismatch environment or something etc.

"np.array() does not excute" What do you mean by that?

Assuming that you're running file in vscode...
You need to select Anaconda environment as your default environment in vscode.
In order to do that:

Press ctrl+shift+p in vscode.
Then type "python Interpreter" in search box.
Select your anaconda env as default env
Run the file

